# Change the attribute of a dynamic element if it passes the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, dynamic, attr

I've a function 'refreshDisplay' which will help me create dynamic elements.
Now, I've a small condition there.
In the 'src' attribute of the image, I'm going to check if the obj.picture.thumbnail starts with '/content' then add '.jpg' as an extension to the 'src' attribute, else do nothing!

Please check the image with class '.myLink' in the code.
How do I achieve this?

Here's the code.

```js
function refreshDisplay() {
  $('.container').html('');
 savedData.forEach(function (obj) {
 // Reset container, and append collected data (use jQuery for appending)
   $('.container').append(
   $('<div>').addClass('parent').append(
    $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Name: '),
    obj.name.first + ' ' + obj.name.last,
    $('<br>'), // line-break between name & pic
    $('<img>').addClass('myLink').attr('src', obj.picture.thumbnail), $('<br>'),
     $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Date of birth: '),
    obj.dob, $('<br>'),
    $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Address: '), $('<br>'),
    obj.location.street, $('<br>'),
    obj.location.city + ' ' + obj.location.postcode, $('<br>'),
    obj.location.state, $('<br>'),
    $('<button>').addClass('removeMe').text('Delete'),
    $('<button>').addClass('top-btn').text('Swap with top'),
    $('<button>').addClass('down-btn').text('Swap with down')
   ) 
  );
 })
 // Clear checkboxes:
 $('.selectRow').prop('checked', false);
 handleEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.attr(function)`, `RegExp.protytpe.test()` with `RegExp` `^\/content/` to match string described at Question, conditional operator to concatenate `".jpg"` or return existing `src` or empty string.

```
.attr("src", function(i, src) {
  return /^\/content/.test(obj.picture.thumbnail) ? src + ".jpg" : src
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works for me, with just one change - .attr("src", function(i, src) {
  return /^\/content/.test(obj.picture.thumbnail) ? src + ".jpg" : obj.picture.thumbnail
})

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$('<img>').addClass('myLink').attr('src', obj.picture.thumbnail), $('<br>'),
```

With

```
$('<img>')
    .addClass('myLink')
    .attr('src', 
        obj.picture.thumbnail +
        ( obj.picture.thumbnail.indexOf( '/content' ) === 0 ? '.jpg' : '' ) ), 
$('<br>'),
```